# Executing a jQuery function depending on scrollbar position

Tags: jquery

I am creating a simple webpage that animates as the user scrolls down.
For an example, click [here](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/).

Obviously, I know that Superscrollorama exists.  It looks to have fantastic features, yet it's still rather confusing to a novice jQuery user like myself.

So I would like to keep to simple stuff.  Here is the code I have made for sliding in a div.  This code only works on page load, and I couldn't find how to execute the function when the element comes in to the browser viewport.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide').slideDown('slow');
});
```

How can I get this animation to occur only when the element is scrolled to?  Can I reverse this animation once the element is once again out of view?  Is it better to just go figure out Scrollorama than deal with this?

Comment: http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/

Comment: Look here for an inviewport solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport